# A dll driver with "hidden" operation panel

Tags: .net

I have a dll driver that is responsible for sending an receiving UART messages.

The dll is incorporated in a working ATE app with no problems.

I want to be able to open another application (exe) that will open a form that will give me access to the UART, and view the messages, and also change UART parameters, and even send message.

What should I add/change in the dll to be able to receive or react to external commands?
How can  "communicate" with the dll (something like DDE?) from external program?

By the way, the UART dll is just one of the dlls that I want to control. I have several dlls that need to be able to react from external program.

This is new to me and I do not know how to do it.

all dlls are .net classes....